How to interact with Custom Resources in the latest Fabric8 Kubernetes Client?
I'm working with the Fabric8 Kubernetes Client and trying to interact with Custom Resources. In previous versions(5.12.4), I used the kubernetesClient.customResources method. However, I've noticed this method is no longer supported in the latest versions().
Here's a code snippet demonstrating the deprecated approach:
private MixedOperation<IgniteClusterK8s, IgniteList, Resource> createIgniteClient(String namespace) {
try (final KubernetesClient client = getDefaultKubernetesClient()) {
// Discover the CRD (if applicable in your scenario)
// CustomResourceDefinition crd = client.customResourceDefinitions().get(/* CRD name */);

return (MixedOperation<IgniteClusterK8s, IgniteList, Resource<IgniteClusterK8s>>) client
    .customResources
    .inNamespace(namespace)
    // ... perform operations (create, read, update, delete)

}
}
What's the recommended approach for interacting with Custom Resources in the latest Fabric8 Kubernetes Client versions (replacing kubernetesClient.customResources)?
Are there any migration guides or resources available to ease the transition from the deprecated method?
